# PDF file download through XHR Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Is it totally impossible to download a pdf file through an XHR request?
I know there are many other discussions already on this topic but sadly, I am still not satisfied with them.
I am using AngularJs and making a request by using its `$Http` method. It is not returning any file download popup. But if I hit with the same URL in a new Browser Window then I am getting a popup.
I have already tried a work-arround and its working fine i.e. `document.location.href = url;` but If I do this then I am unable to show the waiting image till the time the download popup is ready and appeared.
So the work arround is not enough for me. I would like to do it with a genuine way through a request to the server through which I can handle the alternative flows of the outcome as well.

Comment: so in short you want to download pdf file using ajax request?

Comment: Yes, but in an angular.js or jQuery way... so that I can handle all alternative flows. like loading image ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at this JQuery plugin
[jquery-file-download-plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) and here is the demo page of this plugin [demo](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)
. I think its inserting iframe dynamically to DOM and produces look and feel just like AJAX request. It might be helpful for you.

Comment: It worked for me, I needed to add a cookie in the http response on the server side...
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It certainly depends on the size of the PDF file, but this would be a workable approach if the PDF isn't too large:

1. Show the "waiting image" and download the PDF using `$http`.

   ```
   $http.get('http://my.example.com/foo.pdf').success(function(pdfData) {
     ... do something with pdfData ...
   });
   ```
2. Convert `pdfData` to Base64 encoding and use a [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript) to create a URL for the downloaded PDF file.
3. Redirect to that URL.

Comment: How can I convert this pdfData to base 64... I am using btoa function but it is showing some errors...

Comment: Perfect solution for small pdfs with a short lifespan