# how to open a PDF file while returning the file in AJAX request success response

Tags: python, django, jquery, pdf

I get 2 dates, start and end date, via AJAX. I process the data b/w those 2 dates, generate a report and then returns an HttpResponse. The PDF report is now saved in my main project directory. Now I get a response back in AJAX. So, now how should I process the response in the success function, sent back from the sever and open a PDF file.

Thanks.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#report_submit").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "/reports/",
      data : { 'start_date' : $("#startDate").val() , 'end_date' : $("#endDate").val() },
      success : function(result){

      },

      error : function(result){
      }
    });

  });
});
```

**Django view code**

```
def generate_report(request):
    ctx = {}

    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.POST.has_key('start_date'):
            start_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST[ 'start_date'] , '%m/%d/%Y')
            end_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST[ 'end_date'] , '%m/%d/%Y')

            ......
            # PDF GENERATED in MAIN PROJECT DIRECTORY

            with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../../../../gui','Report.pdf')) as pdf:
                response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=Report.pdf'

                return response  # so, now when I send a response back, how should I process it in AJAX success function?
            pdf.closed


    return render(request, 'generate_report/reports.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and send it in the Ajax response. Instead, get your view to generate a unique URL for the PDF, then get the JS to redirect the browser to that URL:

view:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'url': my_url})
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/reports/",
  data : { 'start_date' : $("#startDate").val() , 'end_date' : $("#endDate").val() },
  success : function(result){
     var url = result['url'];
     window.location = url;
  },
```

Comment: Generating a url  means? How will I generate a new url for each file? I've the path to where that file is saved. Does that serve the purpose of url?

Comment: My point is that you will need a URL to serve the PDF from. You need some kind of unique identifier so that the serving view can identify it. Remember that your website will potentially be serving multiple people at a time, so you can't just generate a single PDF "in the main directory": it could easily get overwritten by another request.

Comment: I got your point, but my question still stands that how would I create a url for this PDF file in the urls.py file? Are you talking about serving the static files?

Comment: Yes. You just need a view that takes the ID from the URL, opens the relevant PDF, and then does what your original code above (inside the `with`) does.

Comment: And thats my question is how do I assigna url to this pdf?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been discussed in the following Question... You might need to go for the jquery plugin for file download and please do not forget to set cookie in the response.

[PDF file download through XHR Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260212/pdf-file-download-through-xhr-request)

You might need to add a javascript file for the file download and also use the folowing code to generate the request to the server.

```
$.fileDownload(urlll,{  
        successCallback: function (url)     
        {           
            //success code here
        },      
        failCallback: function (html, url) 
        {    
            //error code here
        } 
    });
```

And on the server side while adding the header etc in the response do the following in response object. i.e.

```
aResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

I hope you can solve the issue and can help others as well.. "Dangling Pointer"

Comment: Let me give it a shot.

Comment: you shouldn't have to download the file.  Just redirect the browser to it.  Remember, now that you have generated the file, it is somewhere on your file system and can be retrieved via URL.  Just pass the URL back in the response and use JS to redirect to it.  You can even, set a cookie to restrict access to it.

Comment: Should I add your above code `$.fileDownload` under success function of the AJAX??

Comment: No. $.fileDownload is itself an ajax request to the server for the file download... It creates an iFrame and then downloads the file and after that it deletes the iFrame... that is how it works. as XHR request can not download a file from the server.. I have gone through many forums...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to call `window.open(pdf_url)` in "success" callback, where pdf_url is the link to your generated pdf report (which you'll need to pass to response).