# How to show a PDF file in a new browser window with ajax POST and ASP.net MVC FileStreamResult?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, blob

I have a Controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(List<int> idList)
{
    Stream stream = ReportsComponent.GetReports(idList);
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

To access that I have the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Reports/GetReport",
    data: { idList : idsList}
})
.then(function(data){
        /*Not working*/
        var blob=new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});

        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(fileURL);
        /*Not working*/
    },
    function(){
        //error
    }
);
```

So far I am getting (with the not working code) a damaged PDF. How can I show the resultant PDF in a new browser window?

Comment: You cannot download a file using ajax. You need to redirect to a method that returns the file.

Comment: Do you **have to** make a POST request? If you change it to a GET request then you wouldn't have to worry about ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261422/304683) (so I'm **not** the original):

- take note about *small PDF* **only**, you can check the other answer about a plugin (I have not tested said plugin).  I can confirm that on a large-ish PDF  this will *not work*.
- I tested with a 24k PDF file (local dev box only - stating that because unsure what effect network latency in real world will have)
- in Chrome pop-up will be **blocked**

`Home` Controller:

```
public ContentResult ReturnPdf()
{
    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/content/pdf/foopdf.pdf"));
    return Content(Convert.ToBase64String(file));
}
```

View:

```
<div>
    <button id="get-pdf">Download PDF</button>
</div>

@section scripts{
   <script>
       $(function () {

           $("#get-pdf").click(function () {

               $.get("@Url.Action("ReturnPdf", "Home")").success(function (d) {
                   window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + d);
               })

           });

       });
    </script>
}
```

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like these,

```
 public FileResult GetReport(string Path)
 {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(Path);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    return new FilePathResult(Path, "application/pdf");
                }
            }

            //file is empty, so return null
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.LogError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

here i passed Path as argument, but you can pass idList, or any string.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Reports/GetReport")",
            type: "Post",
            data: {"Path":"\\F:MyPDF.pdf"}
            beforeSend: function () { },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.IsSuccess == false) {
                    alert(result.ErrorMessage)
                }
                else {
                    $('#divAlert').html('')
                    $('#divAlert').append(result)
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
```

it's just for your demo,

these code working fine at my end, but if you have any query then comment it.